# http-proxy-middleware econnreset error after successful post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, smtp

Developing a contact form using Nodejs/Express and create-react-app following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3eR0X91Ogs. The issue that I'm running into is that when I hit submit on the form the message succeeds, and I get it in my inbox. However, in the developer console, I am hit with the timeout error I set on the `axios.post` located in Contact.js, and in my terminal it logs `message sent`, console log located in index.js, immediately throwing the following error afterward:

```
HPM ERROR: Error: socket hang up
[1]     at connResetException (internal/errors.js:612:14)
[1]     at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:443:25)
[1]     at Socket.emit (events.js:326:22)
[1]     at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:673:12) {
[1]   code: 'ECONNRESET'
[1] }
[1] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/contact/ from localhost:3001 to http://localhost:3000/ (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Does anyone know why this error is occurring, and how I can fix it? The message sends but hangs afterward which prevents the app state from resetting (`resetForm`). At the same time, the `axios.post` in Contact.js doesn't update the state of `sent` to true.

[The Github repo for the project.](https://github.com/dzeignyc/react-contact-form)

Edit: I've been stuck on this for a few days now. Looked at similar questions, attempted ALL the fixes I could find, and this error still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding about how ExpressJs responses work. If you don't send a response to the request, it'll be stuck forever. So all you have to do is to send a response! Also, the `res` variable was re-defined in the callback of `sendMail` function. Here is the fix:

```js
  app.post('/api/contact', (req, res) => {
  // ...
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, mailResponse) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Message sent!');
    }
    smtpTransport.close();
    return res.send(err ? err : 'Message sent!');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Jafar, this definitely helped out. I completely missed that I redefined ```res``` in the callback of ```sendMail``` and I didn't realize that Express demands a response. Thanks!